# ImagePullBackOff: Back-off pulling image "argoproj/argosay:v2"

Tags: kubernetes, workflow, argo-workflows

I have configured Argo workflow on AWS EKS. The EKS is hosted on private subnet i.e **no access to internet.**

1. I uploaded the workflow-controller image, argo-server image and executor-image to my private ECR
2. To install Argo workflow on EKS I modified the [install.yaml file](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/releases/download/v3.4.4/install.yaml) as below.

// Workflow-controller

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: workflow-controller
  namespace: argo
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: workflow-controller
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: workflow-controller
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - --configmap
        - workflow-controller-configmap
        - --executor-image
        - <aws_account_no>.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/argoworkflow:argoexec-v3.4.4
        command:
        - workflow-controller
        env:
        - name: LEADER_ELECTION_IDENTITY
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        image: <aws_account_no>.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/argoworkflow:workflow-controller-3.4.4
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 6060
          initialDelaySeconds: 90
          periodSeconds: 60
          timeoutSeconds: 30
        name: workflow-controller
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9090
          name: metrics
        - containerPort: 6060
        securityContext:
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
          capabilities:
            drop:
            - ALL
          readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
          runAsNonRoot: true
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/os: linux
      priorityClassName: workflow-controller
      securityContext:
        runAsNonRoot: true
      serviceAccountName: argo
```

// Argo Server deployment file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: argo-server
  namespace: argo
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: argo-server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: argo-server
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - server
        env: []
        image: <aws_account_no>.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/argoworkflow:argocli-v3.4.4
        name: argo-server
        ports:
        - containerPort: 2746
          name: web
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /
            port: 2746
            scheme: HTTPS
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          periodSeconds: 20
        securityContext:
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
          capabilities:
            drop:
            - ALL
          readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
          runAsNonRoot: true
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /tmp
          name: tmp
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/os: linux
      securityContext:
        runAsNonRoot: true
      serviceAccountName: argo-server
      volumes:
      - emptyDir: {}
        name: tmp
```

No other changes.

3. kubectl apply -f install.yaml

I am able to run workflows using my ECR images,  but when I run steps/DAG it gives error message. Because in background it is searching for argoproj/argosay:v2 image over internet i.e docker. But as it is hosted in private subnet it is not able to find the image.

Is there a way to upload this image to aws ECR (private repository) and refer the image during installation (install.yaml)?

Answer (score 0):

Pull the image, tag it, push it to your private registry.
However from somewhere you need access to your private registry.

```
docker pull imagename
docker tag imagename registryUrl/imagename
docker push registry/imagename
```

In your deployments use:

```
 image: registryUrl:imageName
```

Now your deployment will try to acccess your registry which should be password protect.

Create a secret in the namespace where your deployment runs, with username and password.

Then to use the secret:

```
  containers:
  - name: my-container
    image: registryUrl/myimage
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: regcred # name of the secret you created
```

The whole process is descibed [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/)

If you absolutly can not access internet to pull/push the image there is another possibility.

```
docker image save myimage -o filename
```

This creates a file with the image, which you can transfer and from there you can recreate an image from that file:

```
docker image import file
```

If that can be an option for you here the links to the docker docu.

[Image save](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_save/)

[image import](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_import/)